# Add Logo to ggplot footer with `+` operator

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, I want to add a logo footer to my ggplot, but I want to do so via a function that I can use the `+` operator with, so I can do: `qplot(1:10, 1:10) + add_mylogo()`

I can get what I want with this:

```
library(magick)
library(ggplot2)
mylogo <- image_scale(image_read("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Stack_Overflow_logo.png"), "180")
qplot(1:10, 1:10) + labs(caption="")
grid::grid.raster(mylogo, x = .97, y = .02, just = c('right', 'bottom'), width = unit(1.2, 'inches'))
```

Which produces:

[image]

My problem is that I want to use `+` to add it to the plot.

So then I tried this:

```
library(cowplot)
library(magick)
library(ggplot2)
mylogo <- image_scale(image_read("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Stack_Overflow_logo.png"), "380")
qplot(1:3, 1:3)+ labs(caption="") +
  draw_image(mylogo, x=3, y = .2, hjust=.7, vjust=0, scale = .5, clip=TRUE)
```

Which produces:

[image]

So now I have it working with a `+` operator, but I can't figure out how to use any sort of relative positioning. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916307/ggplot2-specify-geom-text-position-by-conventional-top-bottom-left-rig) about relative positioning using `annotate` and tried it, but it doesn't work

```
qplot(1:3, 1:3)+ labs(caption="") +
  draw_image(mylogo, x = -Inf, y = Inf, hjust=.7, vjust=0, scale = .5, clip=TRUE)
Error in if (rasterRatio > vpRatio) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

So the first option using `grid` works with relative positioning, but not with the `+` operator, and the second option using `cowplot` works with the `+` operator, but not relative positioning. Is there any way to get both?

Answer (score 6):

You could consider using `ggtext`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
qplot(1:3, 1:3) +
  labs(caption = "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Stack_Overflow_logo.png' width='100'/>") +
  theme(plot.caption = element_markdown())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using `draw_image` is intended to use the plot coordinates, not relative positioning, as you can see in the `draw_image` [help examples](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cowplot/versions/1.0.0/topics/draw_image). For using relative positioning you have to change a little bit your code, adding first the image, and then the plot inside a `draw_plot` call:

```
ggdraw() +
  draw_image(mylogo, scale = 0.2, x = 0.38, y = -0.45) +
  draw_plot(
    qplot(1:3, 1:3)+ labs(caption="") +
      theme(panel.background = element_blank(), plot.background = element_blank())
  )
```

[image: log_test]

In my tests, positioning seems to be relative to the center of the plot (x = 0, y = 0), so you need negative values to go down in y or left in x.
Another *"problem"* is that the logo is added before, so you must convert the plot or panel background to transparent or remove them.