# Consistent positioning of text relative to plot area when using different data sets

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, geom-text

I generate several plots where data may have different `x` and `y` ranges. I wish to place a text annotation in all plots, at exactly the same position *relative to the plot area*.

Example of the first plot, where I add text with `annotate` and position it with `x` and `y` in units of the data:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg) + 
  geom_point(aes(displ, hwy)) +
  annotate("text", x = 6, y = 20, label = "example watermark", size = 8) +
  ggsave(filename = "mpg.jpg", width = 10, height = 9, dpi = 60)
```

[image]

Then a second plot is created, based on another data set where `x` and `y` ranges differ from the first plot.

What is the best way to place the text in exactly the same position *relative to the plot area*, without trial and error?

```
ggplot(iris) + 
  geom_point(aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)) +
  # I don't want to hardcode x and y in annotate
  # annotate("text", x = 6, y = 20, label = "example watermark", size = 8) +
ggsave(filename = "iris.jpg", width = 10, height = 9, dpi = 60)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `annotation_custom`. This allows you to plot a graphical object (`grob`) at specified co-ordinates of the plotting window. Just specify the position in "npc" units, which are scaled from (0, 0) at the bottom left to (1, 1) at the top right of the window:

```r
library(ggplot2)

mpg_plot   <- ggplot(mpg) + geom_point(aes(displ, hwy))
iris_plot  <- ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length))
annotation <- annotation_custom(grid::textGrob(label = "example watermark",
                                               x = unit(0.75, "npc"), y = unit(0.25, "npc"),
                                               gp = grid::gpar(cex = 2)))
mpg_plot  + annotation
```

[image]

```r
iris_plot + annotation
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

The [`ggpmisc`](https://github.com/cran/ggpmisc) package has some convenience functions where coordinates are given in 'npc' graphic units.

You may try `geom_text_npc` (or its sibling `geom_label_npc`), "*intended to be used for positioning text relative to the physical dimensions of a plot*".

Create a `geom_text_npc` layer:

```
npc_txt = geom_text_npc(aes(npcx = 0.9, npcy = 0.1, label = "some text"), size = 6)
```

...which then can be added to all plots:

```
ggplot(mpg) + 
  geom_point(aes(displ, hwy)) +
  npc_txt
```

[image]

```
ggplot(iris) + 
  geom_point(aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)) +
  npc_txt
```

[image]

---

If you don't need the precision of the coordinates that numerical `npcx` and `npcy` provide, you can also specify some basic locations (corners and center) with "words" (see [Specify position of geom_text by keywords like “top”, “bottom”, “left”, “right”, “center”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62842395/1851712)). In your example, the words that best correspond to your numerical position would be `"right"` and `"bottom"`:

```
npc_txt = geom_text_npc(aes(npcx = "right", npcy = "bottom", label = "some text"), size = 6)

ggplot(mpg) + 
  geom_point(aes(displ, hwy)) +
  npc_txt
```

[image]

```
ggplot(iris) + 
  geom_point(aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)) +
  npc_txt
```

[image]

Comment: great answer. good to know about this package

Comment: @Henrik, geom_text_npc is very simple, thank you!