# calculate a value from several rows based on condition on some columns in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset like this:

```
year      city       type   sex  number
2008      London      A      F    100
2008      London      B      F    110
2008      London      A      M    101
2008      London      B      M    111
2009      London      A      F    200
2009      London      B      F    210
2009      London      A      M    201
2009      London      B      M    211
2008      NY          A      F    100
2008      NY          B      F    110
2008      NY          A      M    101
2008      NY          B      M    111
2009      NY          A      F    200
2009      NY          B      F    210
2009      NY          A      M    201
2009      NY          B      M    211
```

I want to plot them in a way that for each year I have sum of F and M as two part of a stack plot and showing the percent of each item.

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/) approach

1. Group by 'year', 'sex' columns
2. Get the `sum` of 'number' in `summarise`
3. Create a column 'perc' by dividing the summarised with the `sum` of the column
4. Specify the `x` as 'year', `y` as sum of 'number', `fill` as 'sex', and 'perc' for `label` in `aes` of `ggplot`
5. Use `geom_col` to return a bar plot
6. Add the percentage label with `geom_text`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(year, sex) %>% 
    summarise(number = sum(number), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    mutate(perc =  number/sum(number), year = factor(year)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = year, y = number, fill = sex, 
            label = scales::percent(perc))) + 
      geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
      geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),  
              vjust = -0.5,   
               size = 3) +      
      theme_bw()
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(year = c(2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L), city = c("London", "London", "London", "London", "London", 
"London", "London", "London", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", 
"NY", "NY"), type = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", 
"A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"), sex = c("F", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M"
), number = c(100L, 110L, 101L, 111L, 200L, 210L, 201L, 211L, 
100L, 110L, 101L, 111L, 200L, 210L, 201L, 211L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Comment: This is works. How can I move the precents label into the bar and rotate then 90 degrees?

Comment: @mans In the geom_text, i specified the `position_dodge` and `v_just`.  I think you can change those values

Comment: I played with them but no success till now. doing more study and trial and error to see how I can do this.

Comment: @mans when you say you want to move into the bar.  where exactly you want to move.  Is it at the middle or top or bottom

Comment: doesn't really matter, but maybe to middle

Comment: @mans just add `aes(y = 10)` in the `geom_text` to bring all of them at the bottom or change the value accordingly for different placements

Comment: @mans Also, there are many options mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916307/specify-position-of-geom-text-by-keywords-like-top-bottom-left-right)