# How can I place a text on a plot (ggplot2) without knowing the exact coordinates of the plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a plot `g` produced with:

```
library(ggplot2)

g = ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) +
        geom_point()
```

Now, I want to add a text to the plot using `annotate` (or anything else). I specifically want the text to appear in the lower left of the plot.

This works:

```
g + annotate("text", x = 12, y = 4, label = "Boring Label")
```

[image]

However, the problem with this approach is that I have to know the plot coordinates (x = 12, y = 4) in order to place the text on the lower left of the plot. I will automate this process for many different plots, and I want to place the same text in the same location (lower left) without knowing the minimum and maximum coordinates of the plot. For example, something like `c(0.3, 0.1)` or `c(x = 0.3, y = 0.1)` (0 = minimum, 1 maximum for x and y) would be very helpful. But this does not work with `annotate("text", x = 0.3, y = 0.1, label = "Boring Label")`.

Comment: Related: [Specify position of geom_text by keywords like "top", "bottom", "left", "right", "center"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916307/specify-position-of-geom-text-by-keywords-like-top-bottom-left-right)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify text position in npc units using `library(ggpp)`:

```
g + ggpp::geom_text_npc(aes(npcx = x, npcy = y, label=label), 
                  data = data.frame(x = 0.05, y = 0.05, label='Boring label'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try this approach, scaling the position by the max value of each variable. Of course, you can change the value of `0.95` depending on where you want the text located.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) +
        geom_point() +
        annotate("text", x = max(mtcars$mpg) * 0.95, y = max(mtcars$cyl) * 0.95, label = "Boring Label")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option is saying that the x and y coordinates are `Inf` and adjust the `vjust` and `hjust` to specify the exact position in the lower left corner:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) +
  geom_point() + 
  annotate("text", x = -Inf, y = -Inf, label = "Boring Label", vjust = -1, hjust = 0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>