# How to annotate a ggplot regardless of dataset?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking to annotate a histogram with some text always in the top right corner. I've been working from similar questions, but my text is always getting cutoff so I just get the first few letters annotated in the plot.

How can I annotate text to the top right of a histogram regardless of the data? I would rather not set x and y based of values per plot as I am making the same plot and annotation for different distributions of multiple columns.

An example of one of the plots with 1 column that I'm trying is this:

```
library(easyGgplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot2.histogram(data=df, xName='Variable1',
                  groupName='Group', legendPosition="top",
                  alpha=0.5, addDensity=TRUE,
) + annotate("text", label= "Adjusted p-value = 0.04535",
             x = Inf, y = Inf)
```

Running this plot with my example data below will give the plot with the cutoff text that I am getting.

Example data:

```
df <- structure(list(Variable1 = c(3.75013, 0.706029, 107.02, 23.1238, 
93.5506, 12.1977, 0.0213773, 0.226452, 58.5638, 0.230506, 2.0151, 
15.8432, 0.507668, 0.206429, 0.0500646, 8.05844, 99.9986, 42.7651, 
NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 21.7922, 
4.33389, 17.6949, 698.604, 0.0783803, 0.254815, 2.27979, 3.80408, 
0.169416, 6.26137, 20.1664, 3.28596, 6.48836, 10.49, 1203.58, 
5.31567, 87.9661, 79.1385, 10.8811, 71.5266, 19.8119, 0.929706, 
1.97972, 36.3889, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 29.6171, 14.0895, 
0.438421, 3.61988, 2.89518, 0.606338, 138.414, 0.0567656, 0.452469, 
14.9471, 0.814494, 9.64228, 9.53371, 107.082, 21.0549, 52.4131, 
48.7998, 5.05289, 6.96671, 148.091, 3.00863, 0.549199, 0.031401, 
0.0286301, 0.137585, 0, 8.88295, 1.2546, 0.372526, 0.102492, 
175.478, 103.448, 0.157544, 2.81689, 0.203345, 0.369321), Group = c("Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Training data", "Training data", 
"Training data", "Training data", "Training data", "Training data", 
"Training data", "Training data", "Training data", "Training data", 
"Training data", "Training data", "Training data", "Training data", 
"Training data", "Training data", "Training data", "Training data", 
"Training data", "Training data", "Training data", "Training data", 
"Training data", "Training data", "Training data")), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I place a text on a plot (ggplot2) without knowing the exact coordinates of the plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69796046/how-can-i-place-a-text-on-a-plot-ggplot2-without-knowing-the-exact-coordinates)

Comment: What package does `ggplot2.histogram()` come from?

Comment: Ah sorry, I am using old code and forgot I am also using ```library(easyGgplot2)```. Also in all other questions I've found and from what I see of that one they are setting x and y with the dataset values which I am trying to avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `hjust` and `vjust` of 1 in your `annotate` call like this:

```r
library(easyGgplot2)
ggplot2.histogram(data=df, xName='Variable1',
                  groupName='Group', legendPosition="top",
                  alpha=0.5, addDensity=TRUE,
) + annotate("text", label= "Adjusted p-value = 0.04535",
             x = Inf, y = Inf, hjust = 1, vjust = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>